# Does VR headsets using smartphones have its own sensors?

Tags: virtual-reality

As far as i know, Samsung Gear VR is the only VR headset that has its own head-tracking sensors and sends sensor data to its mounted smartphone(galaxy series).

Am i getting it right?

From technical specifications of ZEISS VR One, it says

```
Tracking sensors : Internal tracking by smartphone sensors
```

Does this mean it has no in-built sensors?

Just like Google Cardboard, all the other low-cost VR headsets are dependent FULLY on smartphone sensors, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardboard-like headsets are just a way for your eyes to look at your phone in stereo mode, they don't provide any sensors (and very often not even an interaction button like the original google cardboard), these devices typically use your phone's gyroscope to track your orientation.

Comment: This is typically the case, yes (though note it uses the gyro and accelerometer combined, to be a bit pedantic). Note that it's entirely possible to hook up an external, and perhaps higher-quality, IMU over, for instance, USB-OTG. Doubt the GoogleVR/Cardboard API handles that, but OSVR does (I've plugged an external IMU in)